# How to display complete selected table cell on another viewcontroller via UInavigationcontroller

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, uitableview

I created programmatically tableview, I like to display same selected table cell (view) on another view controller. I mean selected particulier cell view I like to display. I need to use via navigation Controller only.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    WriteSuggestionController *writeSuggst=[[WriteSuggestionController alloc]init];


    UITableViewCell *myCell = [theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Access accessory View  as below.
    writeSuggst.bottomView=myCell.accessoryView;

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:writeSuggst animated:YES];


}
```

I see one method but, but I don't have idea how to get back cel from another view.

Comment: What do you get? I mean does your view navigate to the another view or not? and Does it show the tableview with cell?

Comment: 1. create a `UITableViewCell` property in `WriteSuggestionController` and assign your selected cell to it before pushing. 2. Idk why you might wanna do it in the first place. 3. A better approach would be to take a screen shot of the cell and display it in an imageView in next VC.

Comment: i didnt get any think.. when i pass view in buttomview contoller @user3182143

Comment: Did you navigate the view to WriteSuggestionController?

Comment: @NSNoob how to assign in WriteSuggestionController  that cell

Comment: @NSNoob shall i add table delegate method also in  WriteSuggestionController ??

Comment: @user3182143 totaly i like to pass complete(selected ) cell in another view contoller . thats it.

Comment: If you are handling the tableViewCell as a UIView (Simple alloc init) in parent VC then you can simply pass it to next VC and add it as subview, if not (using reusableidentifier), you should pass relevant data to next VC, create a tableView, set rowsForSection to 1 and use that data to populate your new cell in your next Vc

Comment: I want you to make sure that whether do you want to pass data(from selected cell data) or cell to another view controller?

Comment: @user3182143 cell complite view

Comment: @JoyalCliffordSerrão you only want to display that cell right? You don't want to perform any action on it in the next View Controller?

Comment: @NSNoob how pls i didnt get any idea .

Comment: After sending the cell to the `writeSuggestionViewController`, do you want to just display it? Or do you want to perform some actions with it?

Comment: @NSNoob i did. but in next VC it will not display on top, but what ever position is there in first VC  that position it will dispaly

Comment: @NSNoob no action only display, thats it. (on top of view )

Comment: Reset the frame of the cell. Set x & y to 0. It will show on top then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you just want to show the cell's contents in the next View Controller, it is better to just send a screenshot to next View Controller. You can just create a property named `cellImg` in writeSuggst VC. Also in your first VC you need to create a strong property named `viewImage` of `UIImage` type. Then do this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)theTableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        WriteSuggestionController *writeSuggst=[[WriteSuggestionController alloc]init];

    UITableViewCell *myCell = [theTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    // Access accessory View  as below.

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(cell.contentView.frame.size);

    [myCell.contentView.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

    self.viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    writeSuggst.cellImg = self.viewImage;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:writeSuggst animated:YES];


}
```

In your `viewDidLoad()` of writeSuggst VC, write these lines:

```
UIImageView *myCellImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0,yourWidth, yourHeight);//e.g. for a fullscreen width and 30 px height, you will write (0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,30)
myCellImageView.frame = frame;
myCellImageView.image = self.cellImage;
[self.view addSubview:myCellImageView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a property in WriteSuggestionController,

```
@property (assign/copy) UITableViewCell *destCell;
```

then, before pushing the view controller, set myCell value to destCell.

```
writeSuggst.destCell = mycell;
[self.navigationController pushViewController:writeSuggst animated:YES];
```

Comment: i did like that but it will not in top on of the position on 2nd VC